# Publish or forward ipv6 port range to Docker container

Tags: port-forwarding, lxc, docker

I'm building a IPv6 enabled FTP container based on pure-ftpd and I have the problem that passive mode needs the client to connect on any port in the range of 30000 to 50000 to the server on the container.

Right now I don't have a solution for opening the port range for the container. With IPv4 I managed to do that with iptables and NAT, but for IPv6 the NAT table is empty.
I see, that when I publish a port with IPv6, instead of using iptables like on IPv4, docker listens on that port. What kind of magic it does I don't know.

Maybe a solution would be to assign an address to the container, but I couldn't find a way to do that or I didn't see it.

What possible solutions are there, to forward the whole port range to the server in the container?

Comment: It's best to [build your own bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) to your physical network interface so that containers can use IPv6 addresses directly. They will also get unique IPv4 addresses in this setup, so you may not need port forwarding/NAT anymore (or may need to move it to an upstream router).